# SQL select statement ORDER BY relationship to a second table?

Tags: sql, select, sql-order-by

I have table A, which contains a row for an int representing the table B object they relate to.

Multiple As can reference the same B.  B does not reference A

I want to return As ordered by a row in the B object they relate to.

Is there a way to do this in one SQL statement?  Or even 2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can put anything in your `SELECT` list and `ORDER BY` any column you'd like as long as it's in `tablea` or `tableb`

```
SELECT a.ID
FROM tablea
 INNER JOIN tableb ON tablea.ID = tableb.ID
ORDER BY tableb.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
Select (columns that you want to display)
from TableA INNER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.col = TableB.col
Order By TableB.ColumnName
```